# Linking string tuples to a crosstable dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

if I have a data frame of :

```
df1 = matchups 1    matchups 2    matchups 3
      ('a', 'b')    ('b', 'c')    ('a', 'c')
      ('d', 'a')    ('c', 'd')    ('a', 'e')
```

and so on..

and I have a crosstable:

```
df2 =     a     b     c     d     e
      a  NaN  -1.0  +2.0  -8.0   +5.0

      b  +1.0  NaN  +2.5  +3.0    0

      c  -2.0 -2.5  NaN   +5.5   -3.5

      d  +8.0 -3.0  -5.5  NaN   +2.8

      e  -5.0   0   +3.5  -2.8    NaN
```

And I wanted for each matchup to return a value as so

```
df1 = matchups 1    matchups 2    matchups 3
       +1.0           -2.5         -2.0
       -8.0           -5.5         -5.0
```

I'm having issues referencing to both of the data frames and returning a value. Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance

Comment: You've described the issue very clearly but have not provided code or where you are having issues. Please attempt this prior to asking here.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `lookup` here

```
df1.applymap(lambda x : df2.lookup([x[0]],[x[1]])[0])
Out[289]: 
    M1   M2   M3
0 -1.0  2.5  2.0
1  8.0  5.5  5.0
```

Comment: what if my data is string and not tuple?

Comment: @Wen I think that the comment above is asking what I wanted to ask, what happens if instead of ('a','b') , its now ('Captain America','Loki')

Comment: @pyd then you can apply `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: @HarveyKoh you can apply `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: It works fine for the first column, but the second column returns a `KeyError, raise KeyError('One or more column labels was not found')`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
print(df1.apply(lambda x: df2.loc[x[1],x[0]]))
```

Output:

```
    matchups 1   matchups 2  matchups 3
0   +1.0         -2.5        -2.0
1   -8.0         -5.5        -5.0
```